# How to use custom validation message Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-6

I made a validation function for a form but the errors don't be shown, all of the validations and limits are ok but errors don't be shown in blade pages.

```
  $valid=$this->validate ($request,[
       'title'=>'required',
       'meta_description'=>'required|max:150',
       'body'=>'required|max:1000',
        'img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:3024',
        'img_small' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1024',

    ],[
        'title.required' => 'عنوانی برای مقاله ی خود انتخاب کنید',
        'meta_description.required'=>'توضیح مختصری برای پیشنمایش مقاله ی خود تعریف کنید',
        'meta_description.max'=>'متن پیشنمایش نباید بیشتر از 150 کاراکتر باشد',
        'body.required'=>'تویضحات و محتوای مقاله را درج کنید',
        'body.max'=>'توضیحات نباید بیش از 1000 کاراکتر باشد',
        'img.required'=>'لطفا عکسی برای مقاله خود انتخاب کنید',
        'img.image'=>'فایل انتخاب شده باید یکی از فرمت های مربوط به عکس باشد',
        'img.mimes'=>'فایل انتخاب شده باید یکی از فرمت های مربوط به عکس باشد',
        'img.max'=>'حجم عکس نباید بیشتر از 3 مگابایت باشد',
        'img_small.required'=>'لطفا عکسی پیشنمایش برای مقاله خود انتخاب کنید',
        'img_small.image'=>'فایل انتخاب شده باید یکی از فرمت های مربوط به عکس باشد',
        'img_small.mimes'=>'فایل انتخاب شده باید یکی از فرمت های مربوط به عکس باشد',
        'img_small.max'=>'حجم عکس نباید بیشتر از 1 مگابایت باشد',
    ]);
```

And in my blade page for example:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="form-label">title</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" {{old ('title')}}>
                      @if($errors->has('title'))
                       <span class="invalid-feedback" style="color: red;" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                     @endif
                   </div>
```

Comment: did you check the my answer because I have test it and its word fine!?

Comment: no it didn't work properly ... i test all of the possible way in laravel ... i've just this problem jon laravel 6  @Nazari

Comment: i use  dd() an i get the messages but in blade page they are not be observable  @Nazari

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom message using this example code in your controller, also i add condition to it to check the rules you mean code can place after condition.

```
$rules = [
    'title'=>'required',
    'meta_description'=>'required|max:150',
    'body'=>'required|max:1000',
    'img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:3024',
    'img_small' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:1024',
];

$messages = [
    'title.required' => 'عنوانی برای مقاله ی خود انتخاب کنید',
    'meta_description.required'=>'توضیح مختصری برای پیشنمایش مقاله ی خود تعریف کنید',
    'meta_description.max'=>'متن پیشنمایش نباید بیشتر از 150 کاراکتر باشد',
    'body.required'=>'تویضحات و محتوای مقاله را درج کنید',
    'body.max'=>'توضیحات نباید بیش از 1000 کاراکتر باشد',
    'img.required'=>'لطفا عکسی برای مقاله خود انتخاب کنید',
    'img.image'=>'فایل انتخاب شده باید یکی از فرمت های مربوط به عکس باشد',
    'img.mimes'=>'فایل انتخاب شده باید یکی از فرمت های مربوط به عکس باشد',
    'img.max'=>'حجم عکس نباید بیشتر از 3 مگابایت باشد',
    'img_small.required'=>'لطفا عکسی پیشنمایش برای مقاله خود انتخاب کنید',
    'img_small.image'=>'فایل انتخاب شده باید یکی از فرمت های مربوط به عکس باشد',
    'img_small.mimes'=>'فایل انتخاب شده باید یکی از فرمت های مربوط به عکس باشد',
    'img_small.max'=>'حجم عکس نباید بیشتر از 1 مگابایت باشد',
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput($request->all());
}
 
// your main controller code can be wrote here
```

Then add the following code in your blade view page for display errors:

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `Validator` class in top of your controller `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the version of Laravel, from Laravel 5.5 and up, you should be calling

```
$request->validate($rules, $messages);
```

Instead of:

```
$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
```

Maybe this could be your problem?